# Changing Line Endings on Dreamweaver for the MAC (so that files work on linux)

Tags: macos, dreamweaver, line-endings

I am trying to change the line endings in dreamweaver for the mac so that the line endings match linux standards.

Comment: Are you using some broken program that still thinks a Mac’s linebreak sequence is `^M`?  That’s like **so** last millennium. It and MacRoman should both be shot; there’s no excuse whatsoever for such idiocy in a Unicode world.

Comment: adobe is broken in many ways...

Answer (score 4):

Go to Edit | Preferences | Code Format and change the line break type to LF for Unix-style line breaks.